# css- length of border bottom

Tags: html, css

I have a link that's styled with

```
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

And looks like this:

[image]

But I need to resize the length of the border like this:

[image]

Any ideas on how I can do this? Thanks

Comment: For effect like this use pseudo elements as `::after` for your links and define `:hover` , `:focus` and `:active` for it.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it:

```
a:hover:after {
    content: ' ';
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: 25%;
    border-bottom: solid 3px black;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ncxqrkzc/)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use the `::after` pseudo-element, you can give styles to that one.

```css
body {
  background-color:#800;
}
#contact {
  color:white;
  position:relative;
  text-decoration:none;
}
#contact:hover::after {
  position:absolute;
  display:block; content:'';
  left:25%; right:25%; bottom:0;
  border-bottom:3px solid;
}
```

```html
<a id="contact" href="#">Contact Us</a>
```

Or, if you *can't* use `::after`, maybe something like this.

```css
body {
  background-color:#800
}
#contact {
  color:white;
  text-decoration:none;
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative; left:1em;
  width:3em; overflow:visible;
  text-indent: -1em;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
#contact:hover {
  border-bottom:3px solid;
}
```

```html
<a id="contact" href="#">Contact Us</a>
```

(This one is more fussy though; the position of the underline depends on the font size and you may have to fiddle around a bit to get it in the right position.)

Answer (score 2):

It is better to use text-decoration in your situation
Like this

```
.underLineText:hover{
     text-decoration:underline
}
```

And HTML like this

```
<p>Co<span class="underLineText">ntact</span>&nbsp;Us</p>
```

Comment: But then I wouldn't be able to style it to be 3px thick. :(

Comment: Are you sure it's a good idea to insert new markup just to create a decorative look? This can be done all in CSS, which is what CSS is for, after all.

Comment: @Suika then you can use `border-bottom` instead of `text-decoration`

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than one way. I think;

```
<div class="linkDiv">
    <a>Link</a>
    <div class="border"></div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">.border:hover{width:50%;border-bottom:3px solid #fff}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: Try to test this in the fiddle

```
hr {
        border-bottom-style: solid;
        border-bottom-color: #96d9f3;
        border-bottom-width: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        width:20em; 
        overflow:visible;
    }
```

Html:

```
<hr />
```